how to enable accessibility service in Android for debugging purposes
When I switched migrating from react-native with native modules only to kotlin after 'run application' (shift+f10) my application removes my accessibility permission. I wonder is there way to always enable it?
Changing the code seems wrong, because it can be published to the end user.
I opened android studio and changed configuration.
I added 'run external tools' to Before launch option.
with adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services myService
but after permission was granted I could not 'run application' because of 'error running app device is already activating'.
I could fix it using adb kill-server.
But for that action I need manually type that command. Is there a way to create a background task that could set this permission.
Using both commands does not help me restart my program and see the new changes, because I get same error.

first problem with error 'running device' connected to adb I fixed on linux
this helped me.
I used
adb kill-server
sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
adb start-server

Second problem solved.
I created a simple sh script that listen custom activity event and enable accessibility service even after restart. Only need to run it once in background.
#!/bin/bash
PACKAGE_NAME="com.mypackage"

adb logcat | grep --line-buffered "ActivityManager: Start.*$PACKAGE_NAME" | while read -r line
do
    echo "Detected activity start for $PACKAGE_NAME"
    adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services myPacakge
done


Try this

Create a Background Service
Declare the Service in the Manifest
Enable the Service
Grant Accessibility Permissions
Use ADB to Enable the Service
Restart the App

Here is the code for the same
SERVICE FILE
class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        // Handle accessibility events here
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        // Handle interruptions here
    }
}

MANIFEST FILE
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.your.package.name">

    <uses-permission android:name="android:permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />

    <service
        android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
        android:enabled="true"   

        android:label="My Accessibility Service"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />  
         
        </intent-filter>   

    </service>
</manifest>


user permission should be with dot instead colon android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE
but still I have error, so unable to restart my emulator with new changes. "running app"
Medium Phone API 35 is already running. If that is not the case, delete /home/../..avd/* lock and try again.
I have same manifest as you, and service file
